# Login to a specific customer using a file-objectinputstream

Tags: java, oop, authentication

My program is meant to be a banking application. When you start it you can either create a customer or login in as an existing user. For now i can only use customers which i create during the time i run my program but want my program to save the customers even after the program has been closed.

My problem: after creating a customer i close the program-> restart it and try to log in but i get an error: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to nictho7.Customer
    at nictho7.GUI$AL.actionPerformed(GUI.java:221)" this row is mine "nictho7.Customer a = (nictho7.Customer) infil.readObject();" below.

1. "Customer" is a class for my custmers has name,surname & ID.

   2. "bang" is short for my logic class where i store this file.

I reason that the program read from my file searching for object that resembles Customer saves them to the variable "a" and if that variable has an ID which equals the text a user enters it should be fine? But obviously there is something that I'm missing, or maybe sevral things...

**update 12-30
I want to add my customers to a list - customers contains:name,surname,ID & array of diffrent accounts(cred/savings).

1. when i create and run this "new" code(compared to my original post) i get an IOException but I can now access the customer account through the list i created, how can i get rid of that IOException?

2.After adding a creditaccount to my customer i close the program and restart it, when i try to login i recieve this message: >
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to nictho7.Customer
    at nictho7.GUI$AL.actionPerformed(GUI.java:224)<
I understand what Java is telling me, >a boolean can not be cast to a customer cuz my customer does not contain any boolean< but I fail to see where i am trying to do so and how I could fix this?

Line 224 is my refering to the code in my try{ while(true)-loop: a = (Customer) infil.readObject();`

```
    if (ClickedButton == kund) {

            // JTextField username = new JTextField();
            JTextField ID = new JTextField();
            // med ok-och avbrytknapp inbyggd
            Object[] message = { "Personal identity number:", ID, };

            int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                Customer = ID.getText();
                //      if ((bang.searchCustomer(ID.getText()) != null)) {
                //          System.out.println("Login successful");
                //
                //          JFrame frame = new customer();
                //      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //      frame.setTitle("Bank");
                //      frame.setVisible(true);

                //  }
                if (bang.data.exists()) {
                    ObjectInputStream infil = null;
                    try {
                        infil = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\nickt\\eclipse-workspace\\nictho7\\Bankdata.dat"));
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IOEfil");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClassCastException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "classcast111111");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        while (true) {            
                            Customer a = new Customer();
                            a = (Customer) infil.readObject();
                            bang.customers.add( a );
                            if (infil != null) {
                                infil.close();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IOEinlasning");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClassCastException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "classcast");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }finally {
                        // Close the ObjectInputStream
                        try {
                            if (infil != null) {
                                infil.close();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }   

                    if ((bang.searchCustomer(ID.getText()) != null)) {//(a.getPersonalNumber() == ID.getText()) {
                        System.out.println("Login successful");

                        JFrame frame = new customer();
                        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        frame.setTitle("Bank");
                        frame.setVisible(true);

                    } 
                }
            }
```

Customer

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int Arraylist = 0;
    // ------- Instansvariabler ----------
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String personalNumber;

    public Customer() {
        super();
        accounts = new ArrayList<>(); // credit och saving finns med i denna lista.

    }

    // ------- lista med konton ----------
    public ArrayList<Account> accounts;

    // ------- KonstruktÃ¶r ----------
    public Customer(String cName, String surName, String pNumber, ArrayList<Account> a) {
        name = cName;
        surname = surName;
        personalNumber = pNumber;
        accounts = a;
    }

    // ------- Get- & set-metoder ----------
    public String getCustomer() {
        return name + " " + surname + " " + personalNumber;
    }

    public String getCustomerSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setCustomerSurname(String customerSurname) {
        surname = customerSurname;
    }

    public String getcustomerName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setcustomerName(String customerName) {
        name = customerName;
    }

    public String getPersonalNumber() {
        return personalNumber;
    }

    public void setPersonalNumber(String PersonalNumber) {
        personalNumber = PersonalNumber;
    }

    public ArrayList<Account> getAccountList() {
        return accounts;
    }

//  void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException   
    //  {   
    //      name = (String) in.readObject();
    //      surname = (String) in.readObject();
    //  personalNumber = (String) in.readObject();
    //  }

    private void readObject(
             ObjectInputStream in
           ) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
             //always perform the default de-serialization first
             in.defaultReadObject();

            name = getcustomerName();

             //ensure that object state has not been corrupted or tampered with maliciously
            // validateState();
          }
}
```

Account

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Account  implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // ------- Instansvariabler ----------
    private double interestRate;
    private double balance;
    private int accountNumber;
    private static int lastassignedNumber = 1001;
    private double debtRate = 7;
    private String accType;
    private double credLimit;

    // lista fÃ¶r transaktioner och variabel fÃ¶r tid.
    protected ArrayList<String> transactionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // random datum fÃ¶r transaclist
    Random rnd = new Random();
    // Date date = new Date(Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() - rnd.nextInt()));

    // default konto
    public Account() {
        setAccountNumber(getlastassignedNumber());
    }

    // Presentationsmetoder
    public double Withdraw(Account a, double amount) {

        a.setBalance(a.getBalance() - amount);
        return getBalance();

    }

    public double Deposit(Account a, double amount) {
        a.setBalance(a.getBalance() + amount);
        return a.getBalance();

    }

    public static int getLastassignedNumber() {
        return lastassignedNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(int d) {
        this.accountNumber = d;
    }

    public double TransactionToAnotherAcc(Account Acc1, Account Acc2, double amount) {
        if (Acc1.getBalance() > amount) {
            Acc2.setBalance(Acc2.getBalance() + amount);
            Acc1.setBalance(Acc1.getBalance() - amount);
            double a = Acc1.getBalance();
            return a;
        }

        else
            System.out.print("Your requested amount cannot be transactioned due to insufficient funds");
        return 0;
    }

    protected abstract String getspecinfo();

    public String getinfo() {
        return getcommoninfo() + getspecinfo();

    }

    public String getcommoninfo() {
        String info = accountNumber + " " + getBalance();
        return info;
    }

    // ------- Get-metoder ----------

    public double getRate(double balance) {
        double interestrate = balance / interestRate;
        return interestrate;
    }

    public void getbalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public int getlastassignedNumber() {
        accountNumber = lastassignedNumber;
        ++lastassignedNumber;
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public String getAccount() {
        return accountNumber + " " + getBalance();

    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;

    }

    public double getInterestRate() {
        return interestRate;
    }

    public void setInterestRate(double interestRate) {
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTransactionsList() {
        return transactionsList;
    }

    public String inreturnintrest(double d) {
        if (d < 0) {
            d = (d * 7) / 100;
            String info1 = debtRate + " " + d;
            return info1;
        }

        else
            d = (d * (0.5 / 100));
        String info2 = interestRate + " " + d;
        return info2;
    }

    public String getAccType() {
        return accType;
    }

    public void setAccType(String accType) {
        this.accType = accType;
    }

    public double getCredLimit() {
        return credLimit;
    }

    public void setCredLimit(double credLimit) {
        this.credLimit = credLimit;
    }

    //  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException   
    //  {
    //      interestRate = (double) in.readObject();
    //  balance = (double) in.readObject();
    //      accountNumber = (int) in.readObject();
    //  lastassignedNumber = ( int ) in.readInt();
    //  debtRate = (double) in.readObject();
        //  accType = (String) in.readObject();
    //  credLimit = (double) in.readObject();
        //
    //  }
    private void readObject(
             ObjectInputStream in
           ) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
             //always perform the default de-serialization first
             in.defaultReadObject();

             //make defensive copy of the mutable Date field
           //  fDateOpened = new Date(fDateOpened.getTime());

             //ensure that object state has not been corrupted or tampered with maliciously
            // validateState();
          }



}
```

Functions in my Logic-class to call the functions im trying to fix

```
        public int createSavingsAccount(String pNr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
            if ((customers.get(i).getPersonalNumber()).equals(pNr)) {
                SavingAccount newaccount = new SavingAccount();
                customers.get(i).accounts.add(newaccount); // saccounts
                return newaccount.getAccountNumber();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

public boolean createCustomer(String name, String surename, String pNr, ArrayList<Account> b) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        boolean createCustomer = true;
        b = new ArrayList<>();
        @SuppressWarnings({ })
        ObjectOutputStream utfil = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream(data)); 
        for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
            if ((customers.get(i).getPersonalNumber()).equals(pNr)) {
                createCustomer = false;
            }
        }
        if (createCustomer != false) {
            customers.add(new Customer(name, surename, pNr, b));
            //sparar kunden som objekt för loggin
            Customer a = new Customer (name, surename, pNr,b);
            createCustomer = true;

            //name = (String) 
            utfil.writeObject(a);
            //surename = (String) 
                //  utfil.writeObject(surename);
            //pNr = (String) 
                //  utfil.writeObject(pNr);
                //  utfil.writeObject(b);

            utfil.writeObject(a);
            utfil.close();
        }

        return createCustomer;
    }
```

Comment: Does your bankdata.dat contains serialized (using Java serialization) `Customer` objects or common strings?

Comment: please reformat your **code** and **question** (2 else in final section of code without 2 IFs !!!)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time.
I've added alot more code and an update on my problem which i hope will clear things up. @Ivan

Comment: Have you regenerated your file with customers' data after adding account fields to customer class? If you add any non-transient fields to your class Java will not be able to deserialize object that were serialized with different set of properties.

Comment: Is there any way to work around this problem or should i scrap this solution entierly? @Ivan

Comment: There is no easy way(or maybe no way at all) to deserialize your objects with new set of properties from file which was generated from objects with old set of properties. You just need to generate new  Bankdata.dat and use it.